# How to download pdf files one by one using pdfmake

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, tomcat, pdfmake

I am new here and i need your help to find a solution for my crash problem.

I am building a reactjs app and creating a pdf document and then download it by using

```
pdfmake.createPdf.download
```

However, when pdf size is too big, browser gives error and crashes. Therefore, I am trying to divide pdf into smaller chunks and download them one by one. But it executes all download methods and downloads multiple pdf **at the same time**. And this does not solve my issue because I believe I need to give back the allocated memory in order to prevent the crash.

I searched for answers but none of them worked in my case. Still crash happens.

Here is how my code basically looks like

```
exportPdf(rowData)
{
    let org = rowData.details;
    let startIndex = 0;
    let endIndex = 0;
    while(lastIndex != -1)
    {
        startIndex = endIndex;
        endIndex += 25;
        if(endIndex > org.length)
        {
            lastIndex = -1;
        }
        rowData.details = org.slice(startIndext, endIndex);
        pdfMake.createPdf( createDocumentContent(rowData) ).download();
    }

}
```

I want Chrome to download the file for every iteration. I tried to use **Promise**, **setInterval** but didnt work. I also increased nodejs heap size by increasing **--max_old_space_size** to prevent the crash, also didnt work.

I use react scripts to create build and deploy it under webbapps for apache-tomcat-9.0.14. And my node version is v10.15.3.

I appreciate any help you can offer.

Thanks in advance.